# Javascript/JQuery : Need a time Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout

I am trying to implement a jquery function that displays the age of a person. The code for this is at http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

What I have so far works, if I uncomment the alert function, but not with out it. I have tried the javascript setTimeout function, but it does not wait and executes straight away. If I run it with setTimeout and the alert, the popup pops up straight away.

How and where do I implement the delay, so that the html element is loaded before executing the code that fills it.

```
function myAgeLoaded( ) {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date( 1960, 7-1, 18 );
    $( "#defaultCountdown" ).countdown({since: austDay, format: 'YOWDHMS'}).delay( 1500 );
}

function display_text( which )
{

    $.post( "display.php", { content_changed : 1, which : which }, function( data ){ document.getElementById( "main_text" ).innerHTML = html =  data }, "html" );

    if( which == 'abt' ){
//      alert( which );
        myAgeLoaded();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The post `$.post` is `async`, you should put that `myAgeLoaded()` to the function you give to `$.post`, as its what will be called when the request success. As delay will not help much because you can't determine how long will the request will take.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alert will works because it postponed the code execution, so the post my receive the data before you clicked out the pop out, which act as delay, however, you the internet is too slow, or you clicked it out too fast, it may not work.

And from [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), you can see the 3rd parameter you passed in, is a function, which will be executed after the request is success, you should also execute `myAgeLoaded` after you insert the data into your page. So `myAgeLoaded` should guaranteed to see the `#defaultCountdown` after then.

```js
function myAgeLoaded( ) {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date( 1960, 7-1, 18 );
    $( "#defaultCountdown" ).countdown({since: austDay, format: 'YOWDHMS'}).delay( 1500 );
}

function display_text( which ) {

    $.post("display.php", {
          content_changed : 1, 
          which : which
          }, 
          // This is the success callback, it'll be called when the request is
           // response with success code and data.
          function( data ) { 
              document.getElementById( "main_text" ).innerHTML = html =  data;
              // Now the page should be filled with content, call the func now.
              if (which === 'abt') {
                myAgeLoaded();
              }
              
          }, "html");

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the function call to the load section, it is working with out adding the delay!

Comment: You're welcome, you can google `ajax` or `asynchronous javascript`  from google for some knowledge, as it helps understand these things works, as it will come in front of you very often if you're writing js apps, no matter its serverside or client side.